# Missing "Manage Users" on Manage Jenkins page

Tags: jenkins

I'm running a local instance of Jenkins 2.1.  I'd like to create a couple of users with different security access. Till now, I've been working as the generic anonymous user with no security enabled at all.  You can see the alert from Jenkins telling me to set it up on the attached screen shot.

I feel like I'm going a little crazy, but I don't see the *Manage Users* option on my *Manage Jenkins* page that all the tutorials tell me to start with.

Anyone know where else I should look?

[image: Missing Manage Users]

Comment: Have you enabled security? Do this and (IIRC use the defaults to) allow Anonymous to manage jenkins, then you have the chance to manage users, prior to restricting access.

Comment: Clicking Enable security and choosing Jenkin's own user database under Security Realm did the trick.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Jenkins, Standard Security Setup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup):

> Immediately after installation, Jenkins will allow anyone to run anything as user jenkins, which is bad.  This page shows you how to set up basic security using the *Configure Global Security* page.
>
> The *Configure Global Security* page has two sections in which you:
>
> - Set the security realm to determine who is allowed access
> - Set the authorization to determine what each user is allowed to do

See also [Securing Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Securing+Jenkins):

> In the default configuration, Jenkins does not perform any security checks. This means the ability of Jenkins to launch processes and access local files are available to anyone who can access Jenkins web UI and some more.
>
> Securing Jenkins has several aspects to it.
>
> #### Access Control
>
> ...
>
> #### Protect users of Jenkins from other threats
>
> ...

Comment: Does the downvoter–of an accepted answer with a thankful comment of the OP in addition–mind to explain?

Answer (score 3):

In the "Configure Global Security" select "Jenkins’ own user database "
Then the Manage user section will get enabled.

Comment: clean and concise.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Global Security---> security realm ----> Jenkins own user database Finally save it to enable manage user section

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).